# Diference between mvn package tomcat6:deploy and mvn tomcat6:deploy

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

Is `mvn package tomcat6:deploy` and `mvn tomcat6:deploy` does the same thing? I tried on my system both , but couldn't find any notable difference.

Comment: Try `mvn clean` and then each of the commands and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope no difference.
See documentation http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html

"Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase package prior to executing itself."